# How to filter for date type in Sequelize where query

Tags: sequelize.js

Following code does not work:

```
model.find({
  where: {
    id: 1,
    publishedAt: Sequelize.DATE
  }
})
```

I am trying to find model with id=1 but only if its publishedAt value is a date.

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#where

Answer (score 1):

OK, my best option should be filter date values after the query.

```
//Finds out if the given value is a valid date. You can add some more specific checks.
var isDate = function(date) {
  return ( (new Date(date) !== "Invalid Date" && !isNaN(new Date(date)) ));
}

model.find({
  where: {
    id: 1,
    publishedAt: {
      $ne: null
    }
  }
}).
filter(function(record) {
  return isDate(record.publishedAt);
})
```

Comment: Ha, thats a nice workaround, didn´t now about the filter method, going to upvote, but cant accept :).